# How to convert Yaw, Pitch, Roll and Acceleration value to cartesian system?

Tags: geometry, 3d, quaternions

I am having readings of Yaw, pitch, Roll, Rotation matrix, Quaternion and Acceleration. These reading are taken with frequency of 20 (per second). They are collected from the mobile device which is moving in 3D space from one position to other position.

I am setting reference plane by multiplying inverse matrix to the start postion. The rest of the readings are taken by considering the first one as a reference one. Now I want to convert these readings to 3D cartesian system.

How to convert it? Can anyone please help?

Comment: Yes.. I am also having quaternion for same..